# Liquid (Shopify) - Append String is Empty

Tags: string, append, shopify, liquid

In Shopify I am trying to build a string of the current tags in my shopify store.

If I am on the page:

```
mysite.com/collections/all/tag1+tagC+tag4
```

I need to be able to get the current tags as one full string without spaces:

```
tag1+tagC+tag4
```

My code is currently like so:

```
{% if current_tags %}
    {% assign current_filters = '' %}
    {% for tag in current_tags %}
      {% if forloop.last == false %}
        {{ current_filters | append: tag | handleize | append: '+'}}
      {% else %}
        {{ current_filters | append: tag | handleize}}
      {% endif%}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

If I then output

```
{{current_filters}}
```

I get

```
tag1+ tagC+ tag4
```

Firstly how do I go about getting this string without the space after the plus sign? I have tried using `| strip` without luck and also putting my code within {%- -%}

Secondly when I then try and append that `current_filters` variable onto the end of another variable it is blank/empty

```
{% assign current_collection = collection.handle %}
{% assign base_url = shop.url | append: '/collections/' | append: current_collection | append: '/' | append: current_filters %}
```

Outputting base_url just returns

```
mysite.com/collections/all/
```

not

```
mysite.com/collections/all/tag1+tagC+tag4
```

Why is this working when I just use `{{current_filters}}` but not `.. append: current_filters`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing the basic syntax of liquid.

The `{{ ... }}` are used only for outputing data/content, no for assigning.

So when you say:

```
{{ current_filters | append: tag | handleize | append: '+' }} 
// Logic "" (empty value) "tag" (the tag) "+" (the string)
```

you output the empty value of `current_filters` but add to it the value of the `tag` and the `+`. But at the end you are not modifying the current_filters value at all. So at the end it will still be an empty string.

For assigning/modifying values you always use `{% ... %}`, so in your case you should modify the this code:

```
{{ current_filters | append: tag | handleize | append: '+'}}
```

to this one:

```
{% assign current_filters = current_filters  | append: tag | handleize | append: '+' %}
```

In addition you have the `join` filter that will make all of the code above redundant.

You can just call `{{ current_tags | join: '+' }}` and you are ready.

Comment: Thank you. I am new to Shopify so learning from scratch. Appreciate the indepth response and that makes sense now. Is there a quick way to get the tag handles (i.e  `tag | handleize` within the `{{ current_tags | join: '+' }}`

Comment: @odd_duck A quick way will be with a one line like so `{{ current_tags | join: '___' | handle | replace: "___", '+' }}` Where we join them with 3 "_" and we handle the whole string, then we replace the 3 "_" with "+" and you have the handles.